MQTT v 3.1.1 clean session not behaving as expected on connection lost
I am currently testing the clean session feature of MQTT, for my IoT project.
My system architecture is quite simple: I have a subscriber on the same machine as the **broker **(Mosquitto, MQTT version v3.1.1), and a publisher in a second machine, connected via wifi to the main machine. The connection between the two can be very unstable (e.g. poor wifi connection), and it is possible that connection is lost for several minutes.
Due to system requirements, I need that every message that is being sent while the connection is lost, is not received by the receiver.
I am trying to obtain that by using mqtt correctly, and not by brute forcing my clients behaviour (e.g. by forcing senders to stop sending messages if connection is lost).
For this, as far as my understanding of MQTT goes, clean session should be the right choice. Yet, when testing publishing and subscribing with mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub, and simulating the loss of connection by manually removing an ethernet cable between the sender and the broker, on reconnection the subscriber receives (almost) every message that was sent during the loss of connection.
It seems to me that clients subscribe as persistent, or there is the creation of a queue inside the sender that gets flushed when the phisical connection is established again. Or it could be something else...
Procedure
Here is the procedure I am doing, trying to simulate the system behaviour in a simplified manner.

The receiver and sender machine are attached via ethernet cable, in order to simulate loss of connectivity
On the "receiver" machine, I start mosquitto: mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
On the "receiver" machine, I start mosquitto_sub: mosquitto_sub -q 0 -t test.
On the "sender" machine, I start mosquitto_pub in "terminal" mode: mosquitto_pub -q 0 -t test -d -h <ipAddress> -l
I send 3 messages using mosquitto_pub. mosquitto_sub receives the messages as expected.
I manually detach the ethernet cable between the "receiver" and the "sender" machine.
I send another 3 messages using mosquitto_pub. The receiver doesn't receive any message (obviously...)
I manually attach the ethernet cable. Expected result: I would expect the receiver not to receive the last 3 messages. Actual result: the messages are received anyway.

Additional info:

I used qos 0 for both the subscriber and sender messages. I did this to "force" the behavior of messages not being retained. The results with qos 1 or 2, in different combinations, are the same
Clean mode, as per mosquitto documentation, should be set by default on broker, publisher, and subscriber and there is no way to set it explicitly. Only deny it by using persistent mode flags.
I tested this by also giving a short keepalive to the receiver (1s). Unfortunately the args -l (that enable the writing of more than one message via terminal) and -k <keepalive>, in mosquitto_pub, cannot be used at the same time

Logs
mosquitto_pub log
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending CONNECT
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX received CONNACK (0)
one
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
two
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m2, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
three
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m3, 'test', ... (5 bytes))
#Here I detach the cable and send the 3 last messages
4
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m4, 'test', ... (1 bytes))
five
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m5, 'test', ... (4 bytes))
six
Client mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m6, 'test', ... (3 bytes))

mosquitto log:
1719010537: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1719010537: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1719010537: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1719010537: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1719010537: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1719010537: New connection from <receiver> on port 1883.
1719010537: New client connected from <receiver> as mosq-Wze2t5NWmKTwMdQOzi (c1, k60).
1719010537: Sending CONNACK to mosq-Wze2t5NWmKTwMdQOzi (0, 0)
1719010573: Socket error on client mosq-Wze2t5NWmKTwMdQOzi, disconnecting.
1719010587: New connection from <sender> on port 1883.
1719010587: New client connected from <sender> as mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (c1, k60).
1719010587: Sending CONNACK to mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (0, 0)
1719010595: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1719010595: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (c1, k60).
1719010595: Sending CONNACK to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (0, 0)
1719010595: Received SUBSCRIBE from mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe
1719010595:     test (QoS 0)
1719010595: mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe 0 test
1719010595: Sending SUBACK to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe
#The first 3 messages:
1719010599: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
1719010599: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
1719010601: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
1719010601: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
1719010602: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (5 bytes))
1719010602: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (5 bytes))

#Here I detatch the cable 
#(nothing happens)
#After reconnection

1719010634: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (1 bytes))
1719010634: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (1 bytes))
1719010634: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (4 bytes))
1719010634: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (4 bytes))
1719010634: Received PUBLISH from mosq-q9b2Lbd1tARoQKJssX (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
1719010634: Sending PUBLISH to mosqsub|30731-MichaelJe (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))

mosquitto_sub log
one
two
three
#Here I detatch the cable
#...nothing happens
#After reconnection
4
five
six


Have taken a quick look at mosquitto_pub source. Looks like it only reads from the input whist the broker connection is up, and automatically reconnects (so when the connection comes up it will begin reading inputs and your messages will be queued). Maybe try with MQTTX.

The clean_session flag is for subscribers. By setting it to true on a connection, it tells the broker two things: (1) Forget about me when I disconnect; don't save my subscriptions or any messages for me, and (2) If you do have any messages saved for me from a previous connection, throw them away now, don't send them to me, and then forget about me when I disconnect.
But this is not what is happening with your setup. Your subscriber is connected for the whole test, so clean_session is not coming into play.
The issue is the configuration of the publisher. In the case of mosquitto_pub in terminal mode, it appears to be automatically managing the connection; it seems to be detecting the disconnect, retrying the reconnect automatically, and keeping the outbound messages in memory until the connection is re-established.
So, mosquitto_pub is trying to be helpful.
When you write your own client application with an MQTT library, you usually have control of this behavior. (Note that this is just client behavior and not part of the specification). Since MQTT is designed for unreliable connections, nearly all client libraries will inform your application when a connection was unexpectedly lost. Many libraries have an "auto reconnect" feature, and if so configured, will also let you know when the connection is re-established.
So the publisher can just choose not to do anything when disconnected. (Just don't try to send any messages when the library is disconnected).
But what happens when you try to publish when the client is disconnected? This is where libraries tend to differ. The most basic thing is that the library just returns an error to the application ("client not connected"), and drops the message.
Many libraries have a "send while disconnected" feature, with several options. This will cache the out-bound messages until the connection is re-established. The typical options are the max number of messages that should be cached; whether to discard newest or oldest messages when the cache is full; and whether the cache is is RAM or persists to disk.
So, in your case, it would be up to you to manage the remote publisher to achieve your goal.

"The clean_session flag is for subscribers" - I can see how you might come to this conclusion, but it's not really correct. See the spec for a full rundown of the impact of the flag (note that v5 differs); it is important if you are publishing at QOS1+.

@Brits True, my answer was somewhat misleading. But the server can still pass on QoS=1 messages, even if the ACK wasn't sent back to the client due to a closed connection. The odd case is with QoS=2 messages, where the server can just hold the message until the client re-connects and finished the release transaction. But that is not what;s going on here.
